# $Ind_H^G 1_H-1_G$ as direct sum of monomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory

If $G$ is a finite solvable group, it is known (for example, Murty & Raghuram 2000, lemma 2.4) that $Ind_H^G 1_H-1_G$ can be expressed directly (with all coefficients $=1$) as a sum of monomial characters.

What about $G$ non-solvable?

I guess it is one of two options: 1) it is known to be false, 2) the same is expected to be true but not known.

I'd appreciate any information or reference in either direction, or any partial result on $Ind_H^G 1_H-1_G$ that improves on Brauer's theorem.

Comment: Do you mean that $\text{Ind}^G_H1_H -1_G$ is a sum of monomial characters? $\text{Ind}^G_H1_H$ *is* a monomial character.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Of course, my bad, thanks! I'll edit to make it clear.

Comment: Did you try any examples? Like $G=A_5$ and $H=A_4$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not hold in general: For instance take $G=S_5$, the symmetric group on $5$ letters, and $H=S_4$. Then $\text{Ind}_H^G1_H-1_G$ is an irreducible character of degree $4$ (by $2$-transitivity of $S_5$). Thus if it were a sum of monomial characters, it would have to be monomial, implying that $S_5$ has a subgroup of index $4$, which of course isn't the case.

Answer (score 5):

It might be worth remarking that every non-trivial finite perfect group $G$ provides a counterexample. Take $H$ to be a proper subgroup of $G$ of minimal index, say $d$. 
Then if ${\rm Ind}_{H}^{G}(1)-1$ were a sum of monomial characters,  there would have to be a proper subgroup of index less than $d$, since $G$ has no non-trivial linear character, and the trivial character does not occur. But by definition of $d,$ there is no such subgroup.